# How to connect PostgreSQL to react-app website?

Tags: javascript, postgresql

In general, I need to send data from the form to the database. I have a react-app website with this very form that validates data, I have a node.jx app, I created it using npm init, all directories are shown in the screenshot, and I also connected postgre in docker while everything is on localhost under ports 3000 3001 and 5432 respectively.
The bottom line is, how do I do INSERT and SELECT queries in a website?

[dirs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRYRl.png)

I created a pool in database_connect.js

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
user: 'postgre',
host: 'localhost',
database: 'postgre',
password: 'root,
port: 5432,
});
```

then I need to do to get data from the form to the server, write it to the database and vice versa?
What to write to the application on port 3001 and what to write to the application on port 3000?
I will be grateful.

Comment: I'm thinking `user` is actually `postgres` and `database` is `postgres`. Though you should not use the `postgres` database to be your application database. You should create a new database for that.